# DllImport entry point for Interop function not found in ieframe.dll running under Azure

Tags: c#, cookies, azure, dllimport, ieframe.dll

In my C# app that's running under Azure, I need to use Interop / DllImport to call **'IEGetProtectedModeCookie'** in **ieframe.dll**

Here's the signature:

```
  [DllImport("ieframe.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "IEGetProtectedModeCookie", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern int IEGetProtectedModeCookie(String url, String cookieName, StringBuilder cookieData, ref int size, uint flag);
```

I've added ieframe.dll to my project's bin directory, and I have a reference to **SHDocVw** that generates the Debug or Retail **Interop.SHDocVw.dll** file in my obj directory.

When I test this on my dev box, everything works fine, but when I deploy to Azure, I'm getting the following runtime error:

> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point
>   named 'IEGetProtectedModeCookie' in DLL 'ieframe.dll'.     at
>   Predicere.Utilities.LoginUtils.IEGetProtectedModeCookie(String url,
>   String cookieName, StringBuilder cookieData, Int32& size, UInt32 flag)
>   at Predicere.Utilities.LoginUtils.GetProtectedModeIECookieValue(String
>   cookieName, Boolean isFacebookPage) in blah...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we finally found a solution using feedback from S.O. on another separate but related issue.

The problem is that IEGetProtectedModeCookie was not introduced until IE8, but the baseline Azure web instance is based on IE7.

The OS flavor is controlled by the osFamily attrib in :

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="Foobar" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="1" osVersion="*">
```

This setting installs Windows Server 2008 SP2, which is based on IE7.

If we modify the osFamily attrib as follows, we end up with Windows Server 2008 R2, which is based on IE8:

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="Foobar" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="2" osVersion="*">
```

More details can be found in this blog entry, especially if you want to upgrade you Azure instance to use IE9 (which, it turns out, is non-trivial).

http://sajojacob.com/blog/2011/03/startup-tasks-elevated-privileges-vm-role/

Answer (score 0):

IEGetProtectedModeCookie was introduced with IE8. Could it be that only IE6 or IE7 is installed?

Comment: I'm not sure what the default browser on Azure is (if, in fact, there's *any* default browser at all). However, I thought that if I included ieframe.dll with the solution in its 'bin' directory and also made a reference to ieframe.dll (which actually ends up generating Interop.SHDocVw.dll), then I would have all the binary bits necessary on the Azure server.

Comment: why do you want to call IEGetProtectedModeCookie on Azure anyway? Just seems strange.

Comment: Our app has a widget (same domain) hosted in an IFRAME. For IE8, the only way for the server to read cookies shared between the site and widget is to use IEGetProtectedModeCookie. If there are other ways to do this, I'm all ears. But based on our research, there's no other way to do this. When testing this with 'localhost' it works; without, the cookies are invisible to the server.

Comment: We think the problem has to do with 32-bit versus 64-bit DLL's. I'm using a 64-bit box, and we deploy to Azure on 64-bit. But my business partner's deployment box is a 32-bit machine, and we think that his old platform has become the lowest common denominator for our Azure deployment.  I'm getting set up for Azure deployment on my 64-bit box so we can test this theory. If we're right, he'll probably end up getting a 64-bit box.